# Python Pandas get matching data from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 dataframes.

First one, lets call it `requests` and `df1`.

```
id  number  val
0   09876   1
1   12345   2
2   23456   3
3   34567   4
```

and then I have another dataframe, lets call it `receipts` and `df2`.

```
id  item    ref     receipt
0   shoes   34567   #Pos32
1   socks   12345   #Pos33
```

Requests will be my main dataframe that I will be working with and adding data.

I need to add a new columns in requests, based on some data from receipts.

If `df2` contains a ref which equals the `‘number’` from `df1` I want to create a new column in `df1` called `receipt` with the allocated receipt number.

I tried the following using Numpy,

```
df1[‘receipt'] = np.where(df1[’number'] == df2[‘ref'], df2[‘receipt'], ‘')
```

but I’m greeted with `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`, which makes sense cause the dataframes will not have the same order.

Any other suggestions how to get past this?

at the end I'd like my dataframe to look something like this

```
id      number      val    receipt
0       09876       1      
1       12345       2      #Pos2
2       23456       3      
3       34567       4      #Pos1
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at using `map` if join on one column and returning one column, otherwise you want to `merge` your two dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `map`:

```
df1['receipt'] = df1['number'].map(df2.set_index('ref')['receipt'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   id  number  val receipt
0   0    9876    1     NaN
1   1   12345    2  #Pos33
2   2   23456    3     NaN
3   3   34567    4  #Pos32
```

Otherwise use `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='number', right_on='ref', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   id_x  number  val  id_y   item      ref receipt
0     0    9876    1   NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN
1     1   12345    2   1.0  socks  12345.0  #Pos33
2     2   23456    3   NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN
3     3   34567    4   0.0  shoes  34567.0  #Pos32
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a try, but getting ```pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects``` with the ```map``` method

Comment: @RonaldLangeveld Yes, if df2 has multiple rows with 'ref' then  you need to do a drop_duplicates or figure out which ref you need to use.    `df.drop_duplicates('ref').set_index('ref')['receipt']`  inside `map`.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.
Weirdly it doesn’t seem to be having any effect.

Comment: @RonaldLangeveld Typo in the above.. should be `df2.drop_duplicates.....`